# PhoneGap Better Error Handling? (Android)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working on a simple photo viewing app using PhoneGap on Android.. for the most part I can get it working with absolutely no problems but am finding that occasionally when loading a .gif image the page just fails and PhoneGaps just terminates the whole application with an error something along the lines of:

> The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file://android_asset/www/index.html?href=424)

My wonder is if I can have PhoneGap nicely handle that error by not killing the application. I'm doing what I can on the server end to make sure animated gif's don't get filtered into the application but in the event it is and the app can't handle it I can't have my application quitting on me all the time.

Comment: I've seen similar problems as well, and we haven't been able to definitively figure out why. One possible explanation is a link to the debug script when the debug server is down.